# Another instance of the application is already in the process of signing in - Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Unsure of the specific cause of it, but I cannot sign into an instance of Visual Studio 2015 (Update 3) Enterprise. When I attempt to sign in, the login information is accepted in the resultant pop-up window but after the pop-up window disappears the "Sign In" text in the upper right hand corner of the Visual Studio 2015 window stays the same and I see the text "Another instance of the application is already in the process of signing in" displayed as shown here. Note that this is the only instance of Visual Studio 2015 I have running:

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Error]

I have tried un-installing and reinstalling Visual Studio 2015, performing all updates, and resetting the settings to no avail.

How can I get Visual Studio 2015 to accept the login?

Thank you for your time.